# Installing Ubuntu on older Toshiba's Satellite series laptop

Tags: windows-7, toshiba-satellite

I have a laptop with **2.50 GB** of Ram and the CPU being clocked @ **1.46/1.47 GHz** running **Windows 7**. I wanted to install **Ubuntu 18.04** on it. Will it be okay to do it?

Comment: You have given little details about your system, is is i686/x86 only? or amd64/x86_64, and how old and what type of cpu?   I'd use a flavor over Ubuntu (Lubuntu or Xubuntu probably), and tested those flavors on x86/x86_64 boxes with 1gb of ram from 2004+ that came with XP until mid 19.04 cycle

Comment: Compare your CPU  with mine: Intel Celeron T3000. Ubuntu works worse than windows 7 on it. Youtube in browsers works with latencies. You could compare it here: https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core2-Duo-P8700-vs-Intel-Celeron-Dual-Core-T3100/m581vsm1715 Also, my graphic chipset is GM45. So it could be also the cause of poor performance - the lack of good graphic drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be OK, as the recommended minimum requirements are:

- 2 GHz dual core processor
- 4 GiB RAM

The good news is that you can install Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which are lightweight alternatives. Here are the requirements:

Xubuntu:

- Ideally 1 GB of memory
- A processor that supports PAE

Lubuntu:

- Ideally 512MB of RAM
- A Pentium II or a Celeron system are sufficient to run your system

Keep in mind that you should test them with a live CD before installing, and that the simulation on live CD is a bit slower than the installed OS.